# Apache mod_rewrite - prefer files over directories with pretty URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to have pretty urls so http://www.domain.com/foo will return http://www.domain.com/foo.php

The issue is that there is a directory that has the same name. I have another page at http://www.domain.com/foo/bar/baz and right now my server just returns the directory listing of foo when I request http://www.domain.com/foo

Pseudocode:
If the request plus ".php" is a file
rewrite out the file instead of the directory

Actual Code:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}\.php -f  
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

[`MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) could cause this behavior. Try to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the whole path:

```
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php" -f
```

**REQUEST_FILENAME** is just the full path inside **DocumenRoot**