# mod_rewrite rule to match exact URL only

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having an issue with `mod_rewrite` where I want to match—and replace—a specific URL. The URL I want to rewrite is:

`http://example.com/rss` to `http://example.com/rss.php`

That means, if some one were to append anything after `rss` a 404 Not Found response be sent. Currently I'm using this `mod_rewrite` snippet:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# pick up request for RSS feed
RewriteRule ^rss/?$ rss.php [L,NC]

# pass any other request through CMS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php/$1
```

But this matches `rss` and `rss` with anything else added to the end. How can I re-write the above to acces **only** `http://example.com/rss` as the pattern for `mod_rewrite` to match against?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because `/rss` is being redirected twice in your rules by both RewriteRules. Have your rules like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# pick up request for RSS feed
RewriteRule ^rss/?$ /rss.php [L,NC]

# pass any other request through CMS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (?!^rss\.php$)^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,NC]
```

So with above rules it will redirect `/rss` OR `rss/` URIs to `/rss.php` however `/rss/foo` will be redirected to `/index.php` since your 2nd rule is forwarding **everything** to `/index.php`

Answer (score 0):

I was suprised to see that your rules just don't work, because in my first attempt I would have come to a very similar solution. But looking at the rewrite log revealed the real issue.

As discribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659830/apache-mod-rewrite-prefer-files-over-directories-with-pretty-urls) the server prefers real files over directories. So internally `rss/something` becomes `rss.php/something` when applying the rewrite rules and things get weird.

So, one solution is to check if the Option `MultiViews` is enabled for the web directory either in .htaccess or in the vhost configuration. If so, remove it - which is what worked for me in this example.

If you need `MultiViews`, then I guess the only chance is to rename `rss.php` to `rss-content.php` and change the rule accordingly.

One additional note: you might want to add the following line after the `# ... CMS` block to prevent endless recursive calls.

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php/.* - [PT,L]
```

I hope this solves your rewrite problem.